# what kind of data structure should I use in this case?

Tags: c, data-structures

I have a function, it is called inside a loop, it can generate a set of integer for each loop, for example:

result for loop 1: `{1 1 1 2}` 
result for loop 2: `{1 1 1 3}` 
result for loop 3: `{2 1 1 3}` 
result for loop 4: `{3 1 3 2}`

and this function may generate duplication result, for example, result 2 and result 3 is the same. I need to put these results inside a data structure, but can not put the duplication, if the result 2 is the same as result 3, only one of them should be kept, how to achieve it in `C`?

Comment: How large is the range of items in set? If it is small enough, you can use bitmaps.

Comment: it may have up to 8 entrys, but bitmaps is in standard c?

Comment: @ratzip no, it's in math. However, you can use them in C with the help of the `&`, `|`, `<<` and `>>` operators.

Comment: result 2 and result 3 are not the same

Comment: @ratzip yes, bit operations are pretty standard. Usual way of operating with bitmaps is extracting a required byte and then extracting required bit using the bitmap operations.

Comment: I mean is the bitmaps is in standart c? do I need to import any third party library?

Comment: Yes, it is just plain C, even without the C standard library. All you need is just an array of bytes and functions to access a specific bit.

Comment: @ratzip do you think you need to import libraries for using an **operator?** This is C, not C++...

Comment: can anyone provide a example for bitmaps in c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the range of items is small enough, you can use bitmaps as a mean of enumeration. E.g. if you want to represent set of integers in range from 1 to 32, all that is required is a 32-bit integer used as a bitmap:

```
00000001 00000001 00000000 00000000    - for set {8,16}
       ^        ^
       8        16
```

etc.

If the range is larger, use array of bytes, where each bit represents whether value at this position is present in set:

```
#define MAXVAL 1024

typedef unsigned char bitmap_t[];
byte bitmap[1 + MAXVAL / CHAR_BIT] = { 0 };
// CHAR_BIT is defined in limit.h and is equal to count of bits in a byte

void insert(bitmap_t bitmap, unsigned val) {
  assert(val < MAXVAL);
  bitmap[val / CHAR_BIT] |= (1 << (val % CHAR_BIT);
}

int is_present(bitmap_t bitmap, unsigned val) {
  assert(val < MAXVAL);
  return bitmap[ val / CHAR_BIT ] & (1 << (val % CHAR_BIT));
}
```

Comment: but how 11000110 10100000 00000000 00000000    - for set {1,2,6,7,9,11}
00000001 00000001 00000000 00000000    - for set {8,16}?

Comment: @ratzip if bit is set at position `n` from the start of the bitmap, it means that integer `n` is in set. That's why I've asked about the range: if integers may be from 0 to 1023, you need 1024 bits to represent such a set (there may be at most 1024 integers in this set).

Answer (score 0):

In C++, this would be easy. Just use a `std::set` of `std::tuple`s. In C, you have to implement all the functionality yourself or find a good library, but the overall approach is the same.